# How do I get the latest entry in a table that has a unique field?

Tags: sql

I got a table Assignments which contains the logs if a user is assigned with a quiz.What I want is to select the latest user_id's. How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I want the unique id's with the latest created fields

Answer (score 3):

There's not a lot of information to go on but maybe

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is alternative

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table
ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

Comment: It is possible please but i don't see any version specified in the question.This works with all the versions of MSSQL